# How to design for iPhone 5s and 6s plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, viewcontroller

I've an app and it looks different in iphone 5s and 6s plus... Please tell me how to design same for both.
I've attached the screens
[image: This is on iphone 6s and a lot of gap is being left at right side and on bottom]

[image: This is iphone 5s and its good fit perfectly.]

first is on iphone 6s and a lot of gap is being left at right side and on bottom
second is iphone 5s and its good fit perfectly.
How to achieve same on iPhone 6s plus with same storyboard view controller...

Comment: Are you using **AUTOLAYOUT**

Comment: yes but size classes disabled

Comment: enable the **Use Size Classes** in File Inspector

Comment: Its increasing the view controller size and lot of space is left

Comment: @SUDHAKARRAYAPUDI You need to tackle that problem by yourself. You need to decide how you want your app to look on different screen sizes and adjust your autolayout constraints accordingly.

Comment: Do **not** use Size Classes if you want the same content on the screen but just somewhat bigger to nicely fit the screen. Instead, use relative sizes (like width = 50% parent width) or size your views by only specifying the width and height of the spacing between views.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Use size classes and AutoLayout

2.) If you are making app only for iPhone than use Regular Height and compact Width it will help.

For more detail about size classes see these links

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/SelectingASizeClass.html

Comment: bayadi I have one doubt , if I use univeral app which sizeclass I use

Comment: Regular Regular, it will be of 600 x 600 in size